# how to make a space at the bottom of a UITableView in a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to add a footer to the UITableView, there are two ways, either footer for the section, or footer for the UITableView. Both don't work for me because I want to footer always at the bottom of the screen. In other words, floating footer.

That's why after searching, people suggest to but the footer under the UITableView. I would need to resize the UITableView and add the footer through IB under it. That makes sense and that's what I am asking for.

**Kindly I have a specific problem and It's not about footer at all**

My problem is that I couldn't create constrains for the UITableView that locates inside UITableViewContoller, whenever I click `Ctrl` + drag, I don't see the options that I would normally see.

Is that because I'm working with UITableViewController?

This is a screenshot of my hirechy

[image]

**Again I would like to resay that my problem is not about footers, my problem is about how to resize the UITableView in a UITableViewController**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a sample project with a fixed footer. You can download it [here](https://github.com/rashwanlazkani/TableViewFixedFooter). What I have added is:

`ContainerView` 100%
- `TableView` 90% of the `ContainerView` and constraints to the `ContainerView`
- `View` 10% of the `ContainerView` and constraints to the `ContainerView`

[image]

Comment: @deltashade, I always thinks it´s best to wrap elements in a single view. If it´s better than adding it directly in an `UIViewController` I´m not sure but it will give you much more control imo. Try to download my project and experiment with it if you want.

Comment: You are right. This is much better approach. I will give it a try when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. You cannot add a footer on a UITableViewController. For this I recommend using a UIViewController.

Follow these steps if you want to add a footer:

1. create UIViewController
2. Add footer to the bottom and add constraints to the bottom border.
3. Add UITableView to the UIView, and add constraints to the footer.

Also for the controller, just create two classes within the same file, and make one of them as a UITableViewController and the footer as regular class within the file.

If you just want space you should just use UIViewController. Add UITableView inside that, and put constraints on that.

This is one approach, and there maybe many other. Please let me know if I can help you any further.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't resize the `UITableView` of an `UITableViewController` object : your tableview is in fact your main view.
If you want to put a empty space that can't be scrolled below an `UITableView`, you should use an `UIViewController` instead.

Add an `UITableView` and an `UIView` to this `UIViewController` object. 
Set the left, right, and bottom constraints aligned to its superview for the `UIView`, and fix its height with a fourth constraint. Add the left, right and top constraints aligned to its superview for the `UITableView`, and set the vertical space between the view and the tableview to 0 with a constraint.

Comment: Don't forget to set your delegate and datasource when implementing this route.